# A binomial inequality

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I've tried both expanding the binomials as well as trying to deduce something from the hypergeometric distribution, but I don't see how to prove:

$${N\choose n}^{-1}\sum_{i\geq j}{M\choose i}{N-M\choose n-i}{i\choose j}\leq {n\choose j}\left(\frac{M}{N}\right)^j.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the factorial formulas for binomial coefficients and [Vandermonde's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), assuming $M\le N$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}\binom{N}{n}^{-1}\sum_{i=j}^n\binom{M}{i}\binom{N-M}{n-i}\binom{i}{j}
&=\binom{N}{n}^{-1}\sum_{i=j}^n\binom{M}{j}\binom{N-M}{n-i}\binom{M-j}{i-j}\tag{1}\\
&=\binom{N}{n}^{-1}\binom{M}{j}\binom{N-j}{n-j}\tag{2}\\
&=\binom{M}{j}\binom{N}{j}^{-1}\binom{n}{j}\tag{3}\\
&\le\left(\frac MN\right)^j\binom{n}{j}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\binom{M}{i}\binom{i}{j}
=\frac{M!}{i!\,(M-i)!}\frac{i!}{j!\,(i-j)!}
=\frac{M!}{j!\,(M-j)!}\frac{(M-j)!}{(M-i)!\,(i-j)!}
=\binom{M}{j}\binom{M-j}{i-j}$
$(2)$: Vandermonde $\implies\sum\limits_{i=j}^n\binom{N-M}{n-i}\binom{M-j}{i-j}=\binom{N-j}{n-j}$
$(3)$: $\binom{N}{n}^{-1}\binom{N-j}{n-j}=\frac{n!\,(N-n)!}{N!}\frac{(N-j)!}{(N-n)!\,(n-j)!}=\frac{n!}{j!\,(n-j)!}\frac{j!\,(N-j)!}{N!}=\binom{N}{j}^{-1}\binom{n}{j}$
$(4)$: $M\le N\implies\frac{M}{N}\frac{M-1}{N-1}\frac{M-2}{N-2}\cdots\frac{M-j+1}{N-j+1}\le\left(\frac MN\right)^j$